# Is there a way to check if the default values were explicitly passed in to an instance of a dataclass`

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

Consider the following python code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Registration:
  category: str = 'new'

@dataclass
class Car:
  make: str = None
  category: str = None
  reg: Registration = None
 
  def __post_init__(self):
    ''' fill in any missing fields from the registration of car '''
    if self.reg:
      for var in vars(self.reg):
        if not self.var:
          self.var = self.reg.var


r = Registration()
a = Car(make='ford', category='used', reg=r)
# its unknown if b is used/new, so we explicitly pass it None
b = Car(make='ford', category=None, reg=r)
```

In above example, the `__post_init__` is supposed to fill in fields in `Car` class if it was not passed in during creation of `Car` object. However if None was explicitly passed in as the field value (in this case for `category`) it's not supposed to overwrite it from the Registration object. But the above code does. How do I detect what values were explicitly passed in during the object creation vs what are defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be surprised if there were a way to distinguish between
a `None` passed explicitly vs one that the object acquired via
its defaults. In situations like yours, one technique is to use
a kind sentinel value as the default.

```
@dataclass
class Car:
    NO_ARG = object()

    make: str = None
    category: str = NO_ARG
    reg: Registration = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.reg:
            for var in vars(self.reg):
                if getattr(self, var) is self.NO_ARG:
                    setattr(self, var, getattr(self.reg, var))
```

However, you might also take the awkward situation you find yourself
in as a signal that perhaps there's a better way to model your
objects. Without knowing more about the
broader context it's difficult to offer definitive advice, but
I would say that your current strategy strikes me as fishy, so I
would encourage you to thinks some more about your OO plan.

To give one example of an alternative model, rather than using the Registration to
overwrite the attributes of a Car, you could instead build a property
to expose the Registration attribute when the Car attribute
is missing. A user of the class can decide whether they want
the category strictly from the Car or they are happy to take
the fallback value from the Registration, if available. This approach
comes with tradeoffs as well.

```
@dataclass
class Car:

    make: str = None
    category: str = None
    reg: Registration = None

    @property
    def category_reg(self):
        if self.category is None and self.reg:
            return self.reg.category
        else:
            return self.category
```

Comment: Thanks, the use of a sentinel object actually would solve my problem. I will wait to see if there are any better answers, but this sounds like a perfectly good solution.